# Firebase Backfire: model.set() does not sync to Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, backfire, backbonefire

I'm new to Backbone and Firebase. I'm using Backfire, have a collection:

```
var UsersCollection = Backbone.Firebase.Collection.extend({
    model: UserModel,
    firebase: new Firebase( "https://xxxxxx.firebaseio.com/users" ),
});
```

The model itself is not tied to Firebase (was getting "Invalid Firebase reference created" error):

```
var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function() {
        return {
            email: "example@example.com"
        };
    }
});
```

In my View, I instantiate the collection, and I get the data okay, and I can add new models to the collection, as follows:

```
this.allUsers  = new UsersCollection();
...
this.allUsers.add( userData );
```

Works great, new user records appear on Firebase. However, let's say I now want to grab a given user's model and update its data:

```
var userRecord = this.allUsers.findWhere( {email: email} );
userRecord.set( {age: age} );
```

This updates the model locally but the changed model is NOT getting synced to Firebase. I tried `userRecord.save();` afterwards but it triggers a "circular reference" error. Per the docs, `set()` should do it bur clearly something is off :(

Comment: So the real question is why does .save() return a circular reference error, since clearly calling set() does not persist the changes to Firebase.

Comment: Calling .set() does persist the changes to Firebase in the 0.4 version. I ran the same code and I was able to persist to Firebase. What are you using as your userData variable?

Comment: The UserData is fairly simple, has one nested level:  
`{
    "id": "-JDFx3e..",
    "email": "aaa@ex.com",
    "name": "Pete",
    "events": {
        "-Jxfe..": {
            "qty": 2
        },
        "-JzDa..": {
            "qty": 1
        }
    }
}`
The add() to collection works fine. But when I try to set() on the extracted model, e.g. userRecord.set( { events: events } ), that operation works on the model locally but does not "persist" to Firebase for me. Is a standard Backbone model okay here, or do I need `Backbone.Firebase.Model.extend()` -- a bit unsure when to use it.

Comment: Can you put this in a JSFiddle or JSBin? I was able to persist using `.set()` on the extracted model in my example.

Comment: I'm not sure how to set up a Backbone/Firebase with all the dependencies on JSFiddle but it looks like the trouble is when updating the nested object values, e.g. `events`. Updating root-level values do persist to Firebase. For now, I can get around it by JSON.stringify'ing the nested objects under the `events` attribute. Or is perhaps how it's supposed to be handled?

Comment: I put a sample of my [working demo here](http://jsbin.com/lexale/1/edit). Let me know where this varies from your implementation. You can create your own copy for any edits and send that to me as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `userRecord` variable comes back as undefined in this case because the `allUsers` collection hasn't been populated with data yet. The data is still being downloaded to Firebase when you are calling `.findWhere()`.

To avoid this, you can listen to the `sync` event and do all of your actions from there.

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/cagusu/1/edit?html,console).

```
allUsers.on('sync', function(collection) {
  // collection is allUsers
  var userRecord = collection.findWhere( {email: 'david@email.com'} );
  userRecord.on('change', function(model) {
     console.log('changed', model);
  });
  userRecord.set( {age:4} );
});
```

You'll want to ensure your collections are populated before you process any actions on them. The `sync` event is the recommended way to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the `sync` tip. However, it definitely had a valid `userRecord` model when running `set()` on it. I've updated your [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/livuwe/2/edit) to try replicate; specifically I'm trying to update the `events` attribute of the model with a nested object. It seems to be persisting here, although the inner keys are coming back undefined?

Comment: It's the same issue as before. When you update the userRecord it is an asynchronous action. You have to listen to the `change` method to ensure the data has returned. I've updated the answer and fiddle.

Comment: Performing a set on the nested data in my app is a different issue for me (yet to return to it, probably having to do with the structure at this point) but this answer proved very useful elsewhere -- thanks!

Comment: Shoot me an email if you're still having issues with this.